# 'System.NullReferenceException' Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Вот такую ошибку выдает когда я запускаю программу.

```
maxDate = string.Format("where s.dt_create > '{0}'", 
    Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Select().OrderByDescending(x => x["shedule_dt_crt"])
      .FirstOrDefault()["shedule_dt_crt"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff "));
```

Comment: Ну, у вас `FirstOrDefault` вполне может выдавать `null`.

Comment: @VladD А что можно сделать, чтобы решил проблему?

Comment: Получить результат `FirstOrDefault` в переменную и явно проверить на `null`?

Comment: вам самому *удобно* читать свой код? как посоветовал Вам @VladD вынесите получение `dt` из базы данных *наверх*, где предварительно обработайте если пришел `null`. а что за строку вы таким образом формируете? уж не `sql` запрос ли?

Comment: Точно, это ж SQL! Bobby tables жив :)

Comment: @VladD, `null` может быть не только результат _FirstOrDefault_, в случае когда строк вообще нет, но и само значение поля, тогда падать будет уже `ToString`

Comment: @Grundy: Ага, а ещё `dt` может быть `null`. Поэтому комментарий, а не ответ :)

Comment: Можно писать типа FirstOrDefault()?["key"] тогда если метод вернет null то не будет исключения, а переменной maxDate присвоится null

Comment: @VladimirPaliukhovich `FirstOrDefault()?["shedule_dt_crt"].ToString())` так?

Comment: @VladD подскажите ,пожалуйста, в моём коде)

Comment: Да, почему нет) Это быстрая проверка на null, вернет null если объект null, или поле объекта если объект не null

Comment: Только внимательно, смотрите чтобы dt не было null тоже.

Comment: @VladimirPaliukhovich `Только назначение, вызов, увеличение, уменьшение, и новые выражения объекта могут быть использованы в качестве заявления` ошибка такая. на `["shedule_dt_crt"].ToString())`

Comment: не понял как исправить ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста(